# Angular 6 getting same API data for every server call until l refresh app

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, setinterval

I am creating a dashboard for a skype bot. I am requesting data for every 10 seconds.
Problem is I am getting the same data from API. But, when I refresh app am getting update data from API.

I am using the setInterval function to request data from the server every 10 secs.
I also tried with rxjs6 timer Observable and concatmap operator but the result is same as before.

```
setInterval(() => {
    this.initTopBlockData();
    this.getGraphData(this.calenderStart, this.calenderEnd, () => { });
  }, 10000);
```

Iam using the above function and intilizing it on ngOninit lifecycle hook

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
this.initTopBlockData();
this.loadGraphData(this.calenderStart, this.calenderEnd);
setInterval(() => {
  this.initTopBlockData();
  this.getGraphData(this.calenderStart, this.calenderEnd, () => { });
}, 10000);}
```

Above is how I am calling an API.

Comment: what value you are getting in `this.calenderStart` and `this.calenderEnd`?

Comment: `this.initTopBlockData()` is the main method which calls all methods which are responsible for getting data from the server. I am calling that method on `ngOnint` and in `setInterVal()` function

Comment: Hello vijay, It seems like, you are sending same 'calenderStart' & 'calenderEnd' value in each call. Is it getting updated ? Please share your code for better understanding.

Comment: @Chintan Joshi I am calling the same date. I corrected that thanks for the help

Comment: Happy to help, Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

For each API call, the date I am sending is not updating. I Make sure that date is updated and am getting data updated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the passed values of this.CalenderStart and end each time you rewuesting data